# jQuery On() : performance or right syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 button in my HTML. "Approve" and "Reject". When user press Approve button, I want to hide it and show reject button, and clicking reject button hide approve button and show "Approve" button.

I have the jquery working for it, with `live()` method. as I add Reject with `jQuery.html()` method. and it works fine. But now I need to upgrade jquery on project and new jquery need to use `on()` method.

now my problem is when I use

```
$("td").on("click",".approve", function(){});
```

it fire event twice (HTML below), but when I do

```
$(document).on("click",".approve", function(){});
```

it works just fine. Though I do not fully understand which method is more effective and give better performance on mobile device as well as on PC. I often need to have dynamic binding and always get stuck with "on" method. they do not always work as easy as .live method does.

HTML is

```
<table class="applyuserholidaygrid">
  <tr data-id="194" data-date="2014-01-24">
    <td class="holidayreject" >sumit</td>
    <td class="accepttd"><div class=" ui-state-default ui-corner-all "><span class="ui-icon approve ui-icon-circle-check"></span></div></td>
    <td class="canceltd">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any idea what is best method to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the documentation and understand what `.on()` does.  Your problems happen if the `$()` selector matches two elements,or dynamic elements.

Comment: There is no element with class `approve` in your HTML.

Comment: Note that if you don't need to deal with dynamic elements, you can simply do `$('.approve').on('click', function...)`

Comment: @SLaks There's no problem if the selector matches two elements. It only fires for the one you click on.

Comment: The main thing you have to remember about dynamic binding with `.on` is that the selector _before_ `.on` has to be a static element that contains all the dynamic elements you want to delegate to.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right; I meant two _nested_ elements.

Comment: That's true, although that's also a pretty unlikely circumstance.

Comment: @AleksandrM I make correction in HTML. Thanks

Comment: Is your table inside another table?

Comment: @SLaks I did read documentation, but maybe I miss something. I agree that I tend to have 2 "approve" object in different TD, but then it is not a "foreach" it is onclick and should call for Clicked element. i.e. it should click for my span and for it's parent td but should not called for other "approve" classes presence. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @RichardDalton Yes, I have Td > ul > li> table> tr> td> div> span [approve] ... if that make difference.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code, copy/pasted from your files. Here is a fiddle of what you've given us. Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/y4jkg/1/

Comment: Here is your answer td > ... > td > .approve.

Comment: @AleksandrM that is one answer and explain why 2 calls, but which is better in performance? document or td ?

Comment: @SumitGupta: You want it to handle as few extra clicks as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one fires twice because there are nested `td` tags that will both pick up the click event. (Adding [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) will stop it firing twice as it will not continue up the dom tree after being handled once)

```
$("td").on("click",".approve", function(){});
```

With regards to performance, I would say that it is best to have the event bound as close to the target element as possible. So in this case

```
$('.applyuserholidaygrid').on('click', '.approve', function() {});
```

might be best, assuming that the element with `.approve` is dynamically added. If not just bind to that directly:

```
$('.approve').on('click', function() {});
```

As with any performance issue, I would say try both and benchmark them against each other. It might make almost no difference in which case it is probably best to go with the code that is most readable.